# Android ToggleButton always check

Tags: android, button, sharedpreferences, togglebutton

I want to store in SharedPreferences if the toggle button is Checked or uncheck.

```
 toggle.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener(){
         public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)

if(isChecked){             
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("SharedPrefName", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
   editor.putBoolean("check", true);
      editor.commit();

    } 
else   {
  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("SharedPrefName", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
   editor.putBoolean("nocheck", false);
   editor.commit();
}
}});
```

But when I test this, it is always set to check
in `OnCreate()` I added this:

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("SharedPrefName", MODE_PRIVATE);
    boolean value1 = preferences.getBoolean("check", true);  

    if (value1 = sharedPrefs.getBoolean("check", true)){
        psw.setChecked(value1);
    }else  {
        psw.setChecked(false);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the OnCheckedChangeListener, if the checkbox is checked, you save `check` = `true`. When loading, the `if` will always be true, since you are comparing the value to itself (or the default which you gave as `true`) so it checks the box.

If the checkbox is not checked, you save `nocheck` = `false`. When loading, there is no `check` preference (or it has the previously saved `true` value) so the default `true` is loaded.

**Fixing your code:**

Listener method body:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("SharedPrefName", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
editor.putBoolean("check", ischecked);
editor.commit();
```

Loading code (replace the second snippet with this):

```
psw.setChecked(preferences.getBoolean("check", false));
```